# Removing Kestrel binding warning

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-2.1

When using Kestrel in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project and specifying a binding in `UseKestrel()`, a message is logged at warning level:

> Overriding address(es) 'http://localhost:50000/'. Binding to endpoints defined in `UseKestrel()` instead.

This adds noise to our logs, reports a default (and therefore confusing) URL, and shouldn't be a warning. Short of filtering the message by the logger itself, is there a way to configure the web host builder so it doesn't log this on startup?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, that “noise” is not really that noise if you consider that you only get this once when the application starts. So unless you are doing something weird where you need to restart your app, then you will probably almost never see that line in your logs, compared to all those other (much noisier) messages.

That being said, it is actually a useful warning because it tells you that you have configured the binding URL in multiple locations. So the proper action is not to ignore that message but to actually remove the duplicate configurations.

In this case, you are using explicit listen options with `UseKestrel()` so that trumps everything. So you should remove the other configurations. There are a few locations where you should look:

- `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable.
- Legacy `ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS` environment variable.
- `Properties/launchSettings.json`.

Comment: Perfect; that was the intent of my question as I didn't knowingly define/remember defining the default binding URL. The severity makes far more sense in that context. I understand your point about the log entry, however since we are logging to a database and non-developers occasionally analyse these logs, I'm keen to minimise logging any extraneous red herrings (not that it now appears, this is).

Comment: Of course; a default URL is defined when you create an ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio. Feel slightly silly now.

Comment: I'm getting the same warning, where can I find the other environment variables that can cause this?

Comment: Same here @nullPainter. Can you tell us where it is defined?

Comment: @MarioTacke - in my case, it was a silly mistake. From memory, in the VS debug preferences, I had just explicitly set the startup URL to use a different port.

Comment: I have removed the default URL from launchSettings.json and there are no environment variables defined by me. Yet I still get this warning. Is the list in the answer a complete list?

Comment: @Sander Can you try running your app using `dotnet run --no-launch-profile` to explicitly disable the `launchSettings.json`? I’m not sure but I could imagine that the launch profile gives the default even if you don’t have an URL in it.

Comment: This was my issue. I defined the kestrel settings (yaml) but also had `services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions> ...` in my startup. Removed the startup code and endpoints work correctly now since only using the config settings

Answer (score 37):

This is an old question but you can resolve that conflict between **launchSettings.json** and **appSettings.json** with `"externalUrlConfiguration": true`

Kestrel configuration in **appSettings.json**:

```json
"Kestrel": {
  "EndpointDefaults": {
    "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
  },
  "Endpoints": {
    "HTTPS": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:4433"
    }
  }
```

And this is **launchSettings.json** content:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "TestApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "externalUrlConfiguration": true, //add this line
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thanks!

Comment: How/why do entries in launchSettings.json affect production deployments? I've been under the impression that they are exclusively used by Visual Studio

Answer (score 22):

Had the same slightly annoying warning and checked the environment variables and configuration files, but was unable to locate the source of the url list. In the end I used `IWebHostBuilder.UseUrls()` with an empty list of urls to get rid of the warning.

```
 IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder()
   .UseUrls()
   .UseKestrel()
   .ConfigureKestrel(...
```

Edit: For .net6

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseUrls();
```

Answer (score 11):

It can also be a conflict between the configuration contained in **launchsettings.json** and **appsetings.json**

In my case, while developing locally, the Kestrel entry in **appsetings.json**:

```
  "kestrel": {
    "endpoints": {
      "http": {
        "url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "https": {
        "url": "https://localhost:5001"
      }
    }
```

was conflicting with a profile in the **launchsettings.json**:

```
"MyProject-Dev": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000;https://localhost:5001",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

I believe the right place for this is in the **launchsettings.json** file, so removing the kestrel entry in the **appsettings.json** solved my problem.

Comment: That was my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If can help someone, I was looking for something for my webapi in .NET 6
What solved for me was using the code below in launch.json

```
"env": {
  "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5050"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the the previous answers worked for me. I defined my urls in  builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(async options => )

I removed the following from appsettings.json and then the warning was gone.

```
"AllowedHosts": "*"
```